# Windows Server Web Edition 2008 DNS/Domain name help

Tags: web-server, windows-server-2008-r2, web-hosting, windows-server-2008

Hey all, I've just installed the Windows Server Web Edition 2008 on my computer and was trying to find some how-to's on how to set it up to be my DNS for my domain name i have registered. Problem being is that i can not find anything that tells you how to go about setting up a domain name and having it point to my static IP of the server and also how to create the MX records and anything else needed in order to point to it.

Any help would be much appreciated! :o)

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you buy a domain name, you simply add a dns record (host, A Record) for that domain name to point to your IP address. For example, if you buy a domain name (foo.com) from Godaddy (where ever you bought it from) then there will be a section of their web site that lets you create dns entries.

Look for the help section, or search the providers web site.

MX records are for email servers.

A records are for web servers.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply there, lysdexic. However, i am looking for the walk-though for setting up the Domain Name Server for my domain name.

Comment: I see, I must have read that wrong, that's a little different. Here is a good step by step for installing the dns server role on your server. 

http://www.zdnetasia.com/install-a-dns-server-in-windows-server-2008-62040433.htm

What is not included in this article is that you will need to change the primary dns server with who ever you registered the domain name with. 

Also, as a side note, the best practice for DNS is to have two of them one as the primary and one as a slave for failover.

Comment: Whats the difference in IPv4 and IPv6? And which would be best to use?

Comment: A big difference, I guarantee that you are already using IPv4. Stick with that. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4